# Why does the PIL module ImageDraw.Draw exit without an error when I try to draw on a tiff?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I'm trying to open a TIF using PIL and create a draw object. Opening the image works just fine but when creating the draw object, the program stalls for about 2 seconds then exits without an error.

My system is Windows 10. I created an anaconda environment with:

- python=3.9.15
- pillow=9.0.1

I ran the following commands:

```
>>> import os
>>> from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
>>> img_path = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'image.tif')
>>> os.path.isfile(img_path)
True
>>> im = Image.open(img_path)
>>> draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
```

The ImageDraw.Draw causes the program to exit without any error.

One image on which I had this problem is accessible [via WeTransfer](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2475fdf7eace05eb4384a9cd9685686320221205161204/265fc6). I had this problem using multiple tifs, I also tried changing the file extension to tiff and it didn't work. I converted the tifs to pngs and the code worked just fine.

Comment: could you update to a more recent version of Pillow?  there have been a few [tiff related changes](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/CHANGES.rst) since 9.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Updating the conda package to pillow=9.2.0 didn't work so I used pip instead to download pillow=9.3.0 (`pip install Pillow`). That solved my problem.